# Minesweeper - revealing all empty tiles instead of only some

Tags: java

NOTE: I apologize for the text wall, but I'm stuck getting my own code to work.  I've dug through the other similar questions, but I'm not seeing why I can't get this code to search through everything.  I WILL accept semi-cryptic answers that at least point me in the right direction in thanks.

To practice java, and answer a running question I have about minesweeper, I decided to try to build a minesweeper bot to find out exactly what the best possible winning percentage is for a given game start.  I'm still working on getting the right behavior in the game portion of the code though, specifically where I have the game revealing squares that don't have adjacent mines.  I end up with 0's on the edge of the revealed space, instead of my code searching the tiles around it, like below:

```
Printing Field:
 -
 -
 -
 -
 -
 -
 -
 -
 -
 -                    1 1 2 1
 -                  0 0 0 0 0 1
 -                    1 0 0 0 1 2 3
 -                    1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 -                      2 1 0 0 0 0 0
 -                        1 0 0 0 0 0
 -                        1 0 0 0 0 0
```

I am tracking the actual field in a 2 dimensional Character array, and then tracking the revealed spaces in a same-sized Boolean array.  I am including the method below that I am running once another method has found a '0', which marks a space without a bomb.  I have another method which handles printing the revealed parts out to the current field, and can share that if anyone is curious.

```
private void checkAround(int x, int y)
{
    //this pattern is used to parse out the comma to get the coordinates.
    String regex = "[,]";
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(regex);

    ArrayList<String> to_check = new ArrayList<String>(); //the list of coordinates to check.
    to_check.add("" + x + "," + y);
    revealed_field[x][y] = true;  //marking the coordinates as revealed.

    do //iterates through the to_check list until nothing is in it.
    {
        //these next 2 sections handle pulling the next item from to_check
        String temp = to_check.get(0); 
        to_check.remove(0);

        String[] xy = pat.split(temp);
        int a = Integer.parseInt(xy[0]);  //local declaration of x
        int b = Integer.parseInt(xy[1]);  //local declaration of y

        //if either a or b are outside the bounds of the respective axis, we skip the coordinate and move on.
        if (b > height-1 || b < 0) continue;
        if (a > width-1 || a < 0) continue;

        if (bomb_field[b][a] == '0') //if this is not adjacent to a bomb
        {
            if (a > 0 && revealed_field[b][a-1] == false) //adds the square above to to_check
            {
                to_check.add("" + (b) + "," + (a-1));
                revealed_field[b][a-1] = true;
            }
            if (b > 0 && revealed_field[b-1][a] == false) //adds the square left to to_check
            {
                to_check.add("" + (b-1) + "," + (a));
                revealed_field[b-1][a] = true;
            }
            if (b < height-1 && revealed_field[b+1][a] == false) //adds the square right to to_check
            {
                to_check.add("" + (b+1) + "," + (a));
                revealed_field[b+1][a] = true;
            }
            if (a < width-1 && revealed_field[b][a+1] == false) //adds the square below to to_check
            {
                to_check.add("" + (b) + "," + (a+1));
                revealed_field[b][a+1] = true;
            }
        }
    } 
    while (to_check.size() > 0); //ends once we have nothing to check.
}
```

Comment: You put "b,a" in the array, but you read it as "a,b"?

Comment: By the way, this code would be simpler if you wrote a Coordinate class (but this isn't codereview and that's not what you asked).

Comment: Hey, I'll take the feedback, I know I'm new, and I knew that using a, b like that was ugly, but I didn't know there was a better way.

Also, thank you for the cryptic hint, it's what I needed.  I edited the code to save a, b instead of b, a and it works.  THANK YOU!  Now if only I could have the 2 hours back I spent staring at this accomplishing nothing....

Comment: Also, when I said "array" I meant "list".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing `b` first in the list, then `a`, in the entries in the list. But you are interpreting the entries as if they contain `a` first, then `b`.

For example, if the start point is x=4, y=10:

- You add "4,10" to the list.
- You remove "4,10" from the list.
- You check the cell at x=4, y=10.
- You add "11,4", "9,4", "10,5" and "10,3" to the list - instead of "4,11", "4,9", "5,10" and "3,10".